# LC filter synthesis, given transfer function (by expressing driving point impedance as continued fraction)

Tags: filter, transfer-function, passive-networks, network, synthesis

I want to know how to synthesise a passive LC circuit to implement an arbitrary known transfer function.  (I understand that not all functions are suitable, so let's assume \$T(s)\$ is a positive real function; all poles and zeros are in the left half plane; in conjugate pairs where appropriate, etc. etc.  If it simplifies things to assume \$T(s)={1\over{D(s)}}\$ for polynomial \$D(s)\$; \$R_S=R_L\$; or similar, that's fine.  I assume Cauer ladder-style networks throughout for concreteness, but I'm not attached to that topology if an alternative is easier to answer.)

I am following *Electronic Filter Design Handbook 4th Ed.* (Williams and Taylor), and by performing the procedure described there for expanding Equation (1-4):
$$
Z_{11} = {{D(s)-s^n}\over{D(s)+s^n}}
$$
as a continued fraction, I can successfully replicate Table 11-2 (LC element values for Butterworth filters of arbitrary order).  This is exactly what I want, but I am interested in other transfer functions in general and not only Butterworth.

An example of a transfer function I am unable to synthesise is the 5th order Chebyshev low-pass filter (0.5 dB ripple) in Example 2-20.  I can reproduce the pole positions listed in the book (\$-0.105699\pm0.954967i, -0.276724\pm0.590202i, -0.34205\$), and if I apply Equation (1-4) then I obtain:
$$
Z_{11}={{1.1069s^4+1.72666s^3+1.10185s^2+0.597734s+0.13417}\over{2s^5+1.1069s^4+1.72666s^3+1.10185s^2+0.597734s+0.13417}}
$$
Following the same Example 1-1 method that seems to works perfectly for all Butterworth transfer functions, I invert the expression to find the continued fraction, and get as far as:
$$
Z_{11}={1\over{1.80685s-1.81853+{{2.87577s^3+2.02559s^2+1.44231s+0.378163}\over{1.1069s^4+1.72666s^3+1.10185s^2+0.597734s+0.13417}}}}
$$
At this point I'm stuck.  I know the \$1.80685s\$ term is correct, since it agrees with the first element in the solution to Example 2-20, but I do not understand how to handle the \$-1.81853\$ constant term in the denominator.  Such terms had never appeared when transforming Butterworth functions, where each intermediate level of the continued fraction involved only a multiple of \$s\$, indicating a pure reactance?  I can absorb the constant into the continuation of the fraction, but that makes little difference, since then the subsequent quotient is not a multiple of \$s\$.

I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

(Please note that I am looking for **more** than just the values for the Chebyshev example; I realise it would be very easy to find those in any standard table, and also that for those particular functions, closed-form solutions are known.  I would like to understand how to compute components for transfer functions that are neither Butterworth nor Chebyshev, but are too obscure to appear in tables or to have names.)

Comment: You probably missed an *s* somewhere, or divided two different powers. You should know that this method is generally applicable to all-pole filters, only. If zeroes come into play, the topology is no longer a "simple" ladder, but a ladder with adjacent elements in series or parallel, which complicates things. The method of removing poles/zeros still works, and there are books (e.g. Analog Electronic Filters, Dimopoulos), but also other methods, for example see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/522848/95619). ll methods have one limitations or another. Use a dice.

Comment: I would take the first \$Z_{11}\$ and normalize the numerator and the denominator in the form of \$Z(s)=R_0\frac{1+a_1s+a_2s^2...}{1+b_1s+b_2s^2...}\$ that way you have a resistor in dc you can already infer when inductors are shorted and caps open. Then, either you go through identifying the coefficients with \$LC\$ values as nicely documented by *a concerned citizen* or you try to rearrange the denominator as two cascaded 2nd-order polynomials with a single-pole response (provided a term dominates) and do the same with the numerator with two cascaded 2nd-order zeroes. Good luck! : )

Comment: Thank you very much, @aconcernedcitizen!  I initially thought the same thing about arithmetic errors, but after always succeeding at Butterworth transfer functions and failing to synthesise any others, I came to suspect I am either making the same systematic error, or applying \$Z_{11} = {{D(s)-s^n}\over{D(s)+s^n}}\$ to classes of functions where for some reason it's inappropriate.

The answer you cited is very helpful for me, since entering various transfer functions in Maxima and inspecting the subsequent `eq` constraints is very enlightening while I gradually develop intuition.

Comment: Thank you @VerbalKint... I am trying your suggestion on a basic example or two and it feels promising; it's just taking me a while since I have little familiarity in this area and the method diverges from the worked examples in Williams and Taylor.  I think I really need to work on understanding the basics in more detail to the point where I have some intuition behind Equation (1-4) instead of applying it blindly.  The authors don't give much detail on the purpose or justification for that expression... perhaps considering it either obvious, or beyond the scope of the book?